# How can I pass a server side variable into a core tag in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

This expression tag outpus a correct value for me 
    <%=drug.NonAuthoritative%>

while I cant recover the value of drug.NonAuthoritative for use in a C tag

```
<c:if test="${drug.NonAuthoritative}">&nbsp;<bean:message key="WriteScript.msgNonAuthoritative"></bean:message></c:if>
```

the method is

```
public Boolean NonAuthoritative() {
    return nonAuthoritative;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

1. *Scriptlets* and EL do not share the same scope. The `drug` in `${drug}` has to match the name of an existing attribute in the page, request, session or application scope. If you're preparing `drug` in a *scriptlet* instead of in a controller, then you should put it as an attribute in one of those scopes yourself.

   ```
   <% 
       Drug drug = new Drug();
       // ...
       request.setAttribute("drug", drug);
   %>
   ```

   ---
2. (as partly answered by Nathan), [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) relies on [Javabeans specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html). The `${drug.propertyName}` requires a public method `getPropertyName()` for non-boolean properties or `isPropertyName()` for boolean properties. So, this should do

   ```
   public class Drug {

       private boolean nonAuthorative;

       public boolean isNonAuthorative() {
           return nonAuthorative;
       }

       // ...
   }
   ```

   with

   ```
   <c:if test="${drug.nonAuthoritative}">
   ```

   (pay attention to the casing!)

Answer (score 2):

The scriptlet `<%=drug.NonAuthoritative%>` uses the **field** `NonAuthoritative` of the `drug` instance.

The EL expression `${drug.NonAuthoritative}` uses the **method** `isNonAuthoritative()` of the `drug` instance.

To make this work, keep the EL expression as-is, but add this method to your `drug` class:

```
public boolean isNonAuthoritative() {
  return NonAuthoritative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the JSTL is assuming you're using JavaBean standards, so when you call something `drug.NonAuthoritative` in a JSTL expression it's looking for a method called `getNonAuthoritative()` (or alternatively `isNonAuthoritative()`). The scriptlet doesn't make that assumption, it just evaluates what you give it.

Comment: I have defined the method though, thats what the expression tag is evaluating, right?

Comment: @bneil: it would help clarify things if you could add the signature for the method you defined to your question.

Comment: I get this error <h3>Validation error messages from TagLibraryValidator for c in /oscarRx/StaticScript2.jsp</h3><p>263: tag = 'if' / attribute = 'test': An error occurred while parsing custom action attribute "test" with value "${drug.NonAuthoritative()}": Encountered "(", expected one of ["}", ".", ">", "gt", "<", "lt", "==", "eq", "<=", "le", ">=", "ge", "!=", "ne", "[", "+", "-", "*", "/", "div", "%", "mod", "and", "&&", "or", "||"]</p>

Comment: I added the method to the question

Comment: @bneil: i think it doesn't like your adding parens. JSTL has its own syntax, it's very different from Java.